# NSData/UIImage to String

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, base64

Is it possible to convert NSData/UIImage Data Representation as JPEG to a String, to be sent over HTTP to a PHP File to save this string in a database, and then retrive it later on in the application and convert it back into an NSData/UIImage Object?

I have tried Base64 Encoding Libraries but base64 doesn't seem valid as the image doesn't display correctly on a HTML Page.

Any suggestions?

Edit.

I was using the following library:

http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php

And converting in the following way:

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(MyImage.image, 90);
[Base64 initialize];
NSData *encoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];
NSLog(@"%@",encoded);
```

This does chug out alot of BASE64 but when I save it to a file and try to view it, I just get the eror loading image [?] in Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Base64 works fine. In fact, when you do inline HTML images, it uses Base64. There must be something wrong with your attempts. Give it another go and if you don't succeed, update your question with your code and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: Updated the above post

Comment: as a side note: don't store the img data as a string. b64 is fine for transfer but it is bad for storage

Comment: The object that the "encoded" pointer references should be NSString, not NSData.

Comment: Direct convert image to NSData. We can use like that i have answered.

Comment: Check on server you are getting image? May be issue of not proper conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of encoding an `NSData` object to base 64 is so you can represent the data as a string that can be stored or transferred more easily. You then need to decode the base 64 encoded string back into `NSData`. This data can then be used to create a new `UIImage`. Your server needs to do this decoding to get back the original data.

Your code has a mistake. This line:

```
NSData *encoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

should be:

```
NSString *encoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

Notice that you get back a string, not data.

You commented that you wrote the encoded string to a file then couldn't view the image. Of course not. If you want to write the image data to a file so the file is actually viewable as the image, then don't encode the data first. Write the raw image data to a file.

Answer (score -1):

you can convert image to string like this
first convert your UIImage to NSData & then convert that ata into string by using encodeBase64WithData

```
NSString *imageOne = [self encodeBase64WithData:[imageDict objectForKey:@"ImageOne"]];
```

and again string to UIImage like this:

```
[UIImage imageWithData: [self decodeBase64WithString:[registerDataDict objectForKey:@"imageOne"]]];
```

Comment: it contained NSData ,which comes after converting UIImage into NSData

Comment: I have tried to impliment this but I get the error "No Visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'objectForKey'

Implimentation:

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(MyImage.image, 90);

NSString *imageOne = [self encodeBase64WithData:[imageData objectForKey:@"ImageOne"]];

Answer (score -1):

You need to import Base64.h

You can directly use like this way:

```
 UIImage *image = _btnaddCountryIcon.imageView.image;
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
 NSString *base64 = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

directly you can convert to NSString. This code works fine for me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP already stated that they get the encoded string already. All you have done is reposted the same code.

Comment: i am using this thing for uploading image. It's common stuff.

Comment: That's not the point. Your "answer" doesn't answer the question. The OP already knows how to get the base 64 string from the image data.

Comment: Because what i understand is that he is not able to load data to string so i have given the conversion.

Comment: If you read the question, it is clear that he doesn't know what to do with the base 64 string. The question is all about what do after getting the result shown in your answer.

Comment: okie I just think that that is issue regarding conversion i answered...leave it thanks. i take question in another way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24301/discussion-between-nirav-and-rmaddy)